# Exporting a Jar library in Java -- how to bundle its dependencies so I don't get NoClassDefFound / ClassNotFound errors when using it?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've developed a library `L` that made use of some dependency .jar files `D`. I've then decided to export it as a Jar `J`, using Eclipse.

When trying to make use of `J`, I get java.lang.NoClassDefFound / java.lang.ClassNotFound errors.

What's the easiest way to have my library `L` deployed? I'd prefer to have it packed together with its dependencies, but it's acceptable to have them phisically separated from `L`.

I've looked up inside the `L.jar` and the dependencies are definitely there, so it seems like a matter of having a file telling java where to look them up for.

Thanks

Comment: Use Apache Maven (http://maven.apache.org)

Comment: after the exporting the jar, how do you plan to deploy it?

Comment: Zip up the app with its dependencies and use a launcher script. Use something like OneJAR or jarjar. Use a custom classloader that allows embedding jars.

Comment: Isn't there a way to define it manually? I'm really not allowed to use Maven

Comment: You can do any of the things I said manually. "Not allowed to use Maven"? 1) lol, 2) how would anybody know?

Comment: Don't have to check maven pom.xml in source control. Just use it locally to make a distribution bundle

Answer (score 1):

User maven or gradle. These 2 build tools do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create and pack the jar along with dependencies you can consider to use some programming for that. Take a look on [JBoss ShrinkWrap](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ShrinkWrap)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Juno Release(4.2), it's very handy to do this.

1. Run your main class in eclipse to see if your project can run correctly
2. Right click project name and select export
3. Select java->Runnable Jar file
4. Next, select your configuration, if you don't do step 1, you can't select.
   select a export position and give a file name, e.g. myapp.jar 
   select 'Package required libraries into generated jar'
5. fininish

run command
java -jar myapp.jar

Comment: For a library, I think it is good practice to package only your classes into L.jar and zip with other jars to deploy.

Comment: If you want only one jar, you can unzip all other jars into one folder. e.g. mylib and also copy your classes into this folder. then use command: jar -cvf mylib.jar -C mylib/ .

Comment: Before using jar command you have such a directory tree. mylib/org/... mylib/com/... etc. don't forget the last '.' of the command line. the runnable jar can also be used as a lib jar. I think. but it is not good.